# env variables not substituted in docker file

Tags: docker, environment-variables

```
FROM alpine:3.11

COPY out/ /bin/

CMD ["command", "--flag1", "${HOST}", "--flag2", "${PORT}", "--flag3", "${AUTH_TOKEN}"]
```

This is the docker file used. I am loading the env variables during run through an env file.
But the variables are not substituted when running the `command`. If I override the `CMD` and exec into the container I am able to see the envs though. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like it was an issue with the command itself. It was not reading the flags properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running CMD in exec mode. Switch to shell mode and it will work out. As for the environment variables to be present you need a shell. [more reading](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

your example:

`CMD command --flag1 ${HOST} --flag2 ${PORT} --flag3 ${AUTH_TOKEN}`

Full generic example:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim
CMD echo ${env}
```

Run:

```
docker build .
docker run --rm -e env=hi <image id from build step>
hi
```

Comment: try my generic example